# Hiding a TabControl header panel if all the TabItems are disabled

Tags: wpf, binding, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a `TabControl` with custom template, the header panel is a simple `UniformGrid` so that it stretches to the whole width of the control.

I have `TabItem`s with `IsEnabled` bound to different `ObservableCollection.Count` and i would like to hide the whole header panel when all the `TabItem`s have `IsEnabled="false"`